# MySQL port 3306 became filtered when configured with Keepalived on Ubuntu server 12.04 lts

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, keepalived

I'm configuring two load balancer (lb01 & lb02) with keepalived for my two mysql server (db01 & db02) with standard port 3306. There is virtual ip address (192.168.205.10) to access it also act as failover, but somehow the web server in the front can't access this mysql server using vip. Here is my config:

Keepalived:

Only the mysql part that i added here.

## LB01:

```
virtual_server 192.168.205.10 3306 {
  delay_loop 6
  lb_algo rr
  lb_kind DR
  protocol TCP

  real_server 192.168.205.4 3306 {
    weight 10
    TCP_CHECK {
      connect_port    3306
      connect_timeout 2
    }
  }
}
```

## LB02:

```
virtual_server 192.168.205.10 3306 {
  delay_loop 6
  lb_algo rr
  lb_kind DR
  protocol TCP

  real_server 192.168.205.6 3306 {
    weight 10
    TCP_CHECK {
      connect_port    3306
      connect_timeout 2
    }
  }
}
```

I already comment out the "bind-address=127.0.0.1" part in both server my.cnf. Also, remove all the firewall prog from my ubuntu server (ufw or iptables).

Any help?

thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "became filtered"?

Comment: ohh, what i mean is that the mysql port should be open, not filtered..i have scanned the host using nmap

Comment: Gotcha - what nmap means when it says 'filtered' is that no response traffic of any kind was sent by the server in response to the `SYN`.  So let's start by making sure the virtual IP is working correctly - is it responding to ping?

Comment: yes, its responding to ping...seems that its blocked by something that i'm clueless, i already uninstalled firewall,selinux, still no response

Comment: Verify with `netstat` that it's listening on 0.0.0.0?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check if you forgot to remove the mysql option --skip-network from your config file ?

The easiest way to find out if it's a network/firewall problem is to make a telnet connection on the lb* mysql servers port 3306 from the web server. If you can get through it's not a network issue :)

Or use `tcpdump -i ethX port 3306`

Comment: yes, i remove that option on mysql. But somehow its the keepalived config above not working, so i remove it, and now its working...still can't find the correct configuration for this, but so far its working...will try to figure out what might the problem with my keepalived configuration, will keep posted. Thanks all :)